# How do i connect online database with set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

I have 2 databases. 1 of them on local. And other one on mlab.com. When i start app with nodemon, i can connect local database. But when i want to connect database that on mlab. It comes out with problem. I use this :

```
    set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon.
```

and after this i still get local connection. And this code is in db.js file.

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/WiFiBuddy'; 
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        dbURI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
    }
    mongoose.connect(dbURI);
```

and by the way i can connect to online database with mongoshell. But can't connect with command line.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors, or just it just connect to the local DB?

Comment: Just connecting to local DB. But i want to connect mlab database.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows10. Should be something wrong with package.json?

Comment: Try `set NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon.` notice no space after production. Source: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/184#issuecomment-87378478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [an issue on the nodemon Github repo](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/184#issuecomment-87378478), the space after "production " could be causing the issue. So if you use:

```
set NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon.
```

Then the production `if` statement should be triggered

Comment: ok. i guess it works. but now, i get that error : failed to connect to server [undefined:27017]

Comment: Check the value of `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI`. If you connect to it manually does it work? i.e. `mongoose.connect(<your mlab connection string>);`

Comment: No problem :) Glad it's sorted.